# How do I convert a long String to an Array or Database fields?

Tags: java, database, string, itext

I am Busy to make some extention on OpenBravoPOS, to read our invoice from the company where we order the products.

This invoice is created in PDF. and I used the Itext Library, to read specific order lines.
The problem is that I am able to read the pages I need, in one big string.
This strings look like

```
LEVERINGSBON 30/06/2012 27828/2012/NL/WebShop   Distributeur ID nummer: 15099191 Uw distributeur: Klant Naam: FM Point Marcel Snoeck Adres: Zonnedauw 17 5953MS Reuver Telefoon: +31654317017 E-MAIL: yvonneenmarcel@home.nl Opmerking: -  Lp. Rekening Totaal FV/39525/2012/NL     vd Wal Sandra 72.00 1 3 x 354 - Luxury Collection 50ml NEW! 72.00 FV/39526/2012/NL     Slaats Tim 6.00 2 1 x KR01 - Eye Pencil DECADENCE BLACK 6.00 FV/39527/2012/NL     Nabben Britt 44.95 3 3 x E013 - Krachtreiniger 1000ml 24.75 4 2 x E016 -Tapijtreiniger 1000ml 9.20 5 1 x 3 Step Mascara PERFECT BLACK 11.00 FV/39528/2012/NL     Nabben Lieke 32.00 6 1 x 192 - Luxury Collection 50ml 21.00 7 1 x 3 Step Mascara PERFECT BLACK 11.00 FV/39529/2012/NL     Claessens Patrick 12.40 8 1 x P101 - Peeling VERBENA 12.40 FV/39530/2012/NL     Smits Yolanda 56.00 9 1 x E006 - Wasmiddel VIVID COLOURS 1000ml 7.00 10 2 x B023 - Body Lotion 200ml NEW 18.40 11 2 x 023 - Classic Collection 30ml 30.60 FV/39531/2012/NL     van Pol-Thijssen Silvia 34.70 12 1 x 110 - Classic Collection 50ml 15.30 13 1 x N003 - Nagellak HOT RED 7.00 14 1 x P103 - Peeling CHERRY BLOSSOM 12.40 Aantal: 21 Totaal: 258.05 € 1.17.4564.29482 1/1        "
```

What I tried to do is read each line, and determine if this is an order row, and if so, I needed to put it in database.

One order row look like

```
2 1 x KR01 - Eye Pencil DECADENCE BLACK 6.00
```

You can read this as follows; Order Row number 2, quantity 1 of product KR01 Description Eye Pencil Decadence Black, with Price of 6.00

Is there a simple way to read this long string and sepparte it with correct order lines.

Thanks for your reply

My code until now is:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package part4.chapter15;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class ExtractPageContent {

    /** The original PDF that will be parsed. */
    public static final String PREFACE = "C:/Users/marcel/Documents/FM/NL/FMPoint        /Kassa_voorraad_software/PDF-Itext/PDF_Results_Import_Files/small.pdf" ;
    /** The resulting text file. */
    public static final String RESULT = "C:/Users/marcel/Documents/FM/NL/FMPoint        /Kassa_voorraad_software/PDF-Itext/PDF_Results_Import_Files/sample-            result.txt" ;

    /**
     * Parses a PDF to a plain text file.
     * @param pdf the original PDF
     * @param txt the resulting text
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void parsePdf(String pdf, String txt) throws IOException {

        /** Putting result in Array, to be able extract to Table */
        PdfArray array;

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
        PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(txt));
        TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            strategy = parser.processContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
            String str = strategy.getResultantText();
            CharSequence FindPage = "Lp. Rekening Totaal"; 
            if  (str.contains(FindPage)){ 
              out.println(strategy.getResultantText());
        }
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param    args    no arguments needed
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new ExtractPageContent().parsePdf(PREFACE, RESULT);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can design a `regex` to solve this in many different ways. Here is one:

```
    String pdf = "LEVERINGSBON 30/06/2012 27828/2012/NL/WebShop   Distributeur ID nummer: 15099191 Uw distributeur: Klant Naam: FM Point Marcel Snoeck Adres: Zonnedauw 17 5953MS Reuver Telefoon: +31654317017 E-MAIL: yvonneenmarcel@home.nl Opmerking: - Lp. Rekening Totaal FV/39525/2012/NL     vd Wal Sandra 72.00 1 3 x 354 - Luxury Collection 50ml NEW! 72.00 FV/39526/2012/NL     Slaats Tim 6.00 2 1 x KR01 - Eye Pencil DECADENCE BLACK 6.00 FV/39527/2012/NL     Nabben Britt 44.95 3 3 x E013 - Krachtreiniger 1000ml 24.75 4 2 x E016 -Tapijtreiniger 1000ml 9.20 5 1 x 3 Step Mascara PERFECT BLACK 11.00 FV/39528/2012/NL     Nabben Lieke 32.00 6 1 x 192 - Luxury Collection 50ml 21.00 7 1 x 3 Step Mascara PERFECT BLACK 11.00 FV/39529/2012/NL     Claessens Patrick 12.40 8 1 x P101 - Peeling VERBENA 12.40 FV/39530/2012/NL     Smits Yolanda 56.00 9 1 x E006 - Wasmiddel VIVID COLOURS 1000ml 7.00 10 2 x B023 - Body Lotion 200ml NEW 18.40 11 2 x 023 - Classic Collection 30ml 30.60 FV/39531/2012/NL     van Pol-Thijssen Silvia 34.70 12 1 x 110 - Classic Collection 50ml 15.30 13 1 x N003 - Nagellak HOT RED 7.00 14 1 x P103 - Peeling CHERRY BLOSSOM 12.40 Aantal: 21 Totaal: 258.05 € 1.17.4564.29482 1/1        ";
    String patternString = "\\d\\s\\d\\sx.*?\\d\\.\\d\\d";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(patternString).matcher(pdf);
    List<String> dataRows = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        dataRows.add(matcher.group());
    }
    System.out.println(dataRows);
```

**Explanation of the regex:**
`\\d\\s\\d\\sx`: Match number, space, number, space, 'x'
`.*?`: match any number of any character, but match non-greedy [Why is this important?](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
`\\d\.\\d\\d`: Match the last number with two decimals
This will probably have to be adjusted depended on how your data varies, but it should be a good starting point.

If you need a list of a custom data structure instead of String, you can get the individual parts of the match like this:

```
...  
String patternString = "(\\d)\\s(\\d)\\sx.*?\\d\\.\\d\\d";
...
while (matcher.find()) {
    MyDataObj m = new MyDataObj();
    m.setSomeField(dataRows.add(matcher.group(1)));
    m.setAnotherField(dataRows.add(matcher.group(2)));
}
```

Just enclose every value you wish to keep in parathensis in the pattern and retrieve them using `matcher.group(1)`, `matcher.group(2)` etc. (`matcher.group(0)` gives you the entire match)

Comment: Hi This was very helpfull for me, but I have still some questions. These Order Rows start with order row number 1 until many, could be 100. There are many special Characters

Comment: If you change the first `\\d` to `\\d+` it goes from matching 1 number to matching 1 or more numbers. This should allow you to parse the row number even if it becomes large.

Comment: This row looks like 
9\x201\xC2\xA0x\xC2\xA0E006\xC2\xA0-\x20Wasmiddel\x20VIVID\x20COLOURS\x201000ml\x207.00\r\n10\x202\xC2\xA0x\xC2\xA0B023\xC2\xA0-\x20Body\x20Lotion\x20200ml\x20NEW\x2018.40

Comment: I Used the following information for testing
http://myregextester.com/
and for find out what pattern could be
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/

Comment: The current Pattern looks like "\\d+\\s\\d+\\xC2\\xA0x\\xC2\\xA0.*?\\xC2\\xA0-\\s.*?" What I missed is the article description and Price.

Comment: You can probably remove a few of the characters from that, you don't need to be that specific I believe. This should be enough for you to get all fields with matcher.group: `"(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)\\sx\\s(\\d+)\\s-\\s(.*?)\\s(\\d+\\.\\d+)"`

Comment: Hmm. It seems the product can have letters in it as well as numbers, so the third `(\\d+)` should probably be changed to `(\\w+)`, (1 or more of any word character).

Comment: I am Almost there, I have one question how can I capture a string of multiple words, this could be 1 word or 2 words, or 5 words, but it always followed with the price 7.00 or 18.40 or other value of the price.

Comment: The price has always .xx, Example 18.40 or 7.00 or 10.90 etc The Price has always 2 decimal behind the decimal sign.

Comment: My regex should give you a clue. As long as you match both sides of the multiple words section, a `(.*?)` in the middle should match that.

Comment: The order line start always with /r/n.
and ends with the price xx.xx
The Product Description could be multiple words and the words are sometimes sepperated with \x20 (spaces) and sometimes with \xC2\xA0

Comment: Ok, sounds like you have your answer right there, something along the lines of `"\\r\\n(.*?)\\d+\\.\\d{2}"`

Comment: It seems to work on website [link](http://myregextester.com/index.php) import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("\\r\\n(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)(.*?)\\d+\\.\\d{2}");
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}

Comment: But when I put this code in Netbeans It doesn't work. I have to Find out what go wrong. But this information was very helpfull Thanks for you support.

Comment: please could you give me an Hint how to use the Data Object group.
I have tried But Didn't worked.
It mention that it could not find DataObject in NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

The Result of the Answer are Great
The Following Code results to the following:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package part4.chapter15;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ExtractPageContent {

/** The original PDF that will be parsed. */
    public static final String PREFACE = "C:/Users/marcel/Documents/FM/NL/FMPoint/Kassa_voorraad_software/PDF-Itext/PDF_Results_Import_Files/big.pdf" ;
    /** The resulting text file. */
    public static final String RESULT = "C:/Users/marcel/Documents/FM/NL/FMPoint/Kassa_voorraad_software/PDF-Itext/PDF_Results_Import_Files/sample-result.txt" ;

    /**
     * Parses a PDF to a plain text file.
     * @param pdf the original PDF
     * @param txt the resulting text
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void parsePdf(String pdf, String txt) throws IOException {

        /** Putting result in Array, to be able extract to Table */
        PdfArray array;

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
        PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(txt));
        TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            strategy = parser.processContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
            String str = strategy.getResultantText();
            CharSequence FindPage = "Lp. Rekening Totaal"; 
            if  (str.contains(FindPage)){ 
/*                Pattern re =  Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)(\\xA0)x(\\xA0)(.*?)(\\d+\\.\\d{2})"); */
                /* Pattern for orders of Artikels with product Code */
                Pattern re2 =  Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)(\\xA0)x(\\xA0)(\\w+)(\\xA0)-\\s(.*?)(\\d+\\.\\d{2})"); 
                Matcher m = re2.matcher(str);
                int mIdx = 0;
                while (m.find()){
                    for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
                        /*System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));*/
                        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
                    }
                    mIdx++;
                }

/**     System.out.println(dataRows); */

          out.println(strategy.getResultantText());
    }
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}


/**
 * Main method.
 * @param    args    no arguments needed
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new ExtractPageContent().parsePdf(PREFACE, RESULT);
}

}
```

The OUtput Results looks like as follows.

*Complete Order Row* [0][0] = 4 3 x 023 - Classic Collection 30ml 45.90

*Row number* [0][1] = 4

*Quatinty* [0][2] = 3

*Empty* [0][3] =

*Empty* [0][4] =

*Product Code* [0][5] = 023

*Empty* [0][6] =

*Product Description* [0][7] = Classic Collection 30ml

*Price* [0][8] = 45.90

[1][0] = 5 2 x C052 - Hand and Nail Cream 100ml NEW 15.20

[1][1] = 5

[1][2] = 2

[1][3] =

[1][4] =

[1][5] = C052

[1][6] =

[1][7] = Hand and Nail Cream 100ml NEW

[1][8] = 15.20

Thanks for this Great Support